Error message not displaying for all inputs
I am trying to add my error message and icon for all inputs that are invalid, however, it only works for the first input. What am i doing wrong? This is not my full solution just a piece of code that is not working, I intend to solve the rest on my own.
I tried using input.value to but that did not work either.


const input = document.querySelectorAll("input");

input.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("invalid", getErrorMsg);

  input.addEventListener("focus", removeErrorMsg);


})

function getErrorMsg(e) {
  const errorIcon = document.querySelector(".error-icon");
  const errorTxt = document.querySelector(".error-txt");
  errorIcon.classList.add("active");
  errorTxt.classList.add("active");

};

function removeErrorMsg(e) {
  const errorIcon = document.querySelector(".error-icon");
  const errorTxt = document.querySelector(".error-txt");
  errorIcon.classList.remove("active");
  errorTxt.classList.remove("active");
}
.inputDiv {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.error-icon {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 30px;
}

.error-txt {
  display: none;
  color: var(--CLR-RED);
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: var(--FW-BOLD);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: 0;
}

.error-icon.active,
.error-txt.active {
  display: block;
}
<form class="formContainer">
  <div class="inputDiv">
    <input class="input" type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
    <img class="error-icon" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
    <p class="error-txt">First Name cannot be empty</p>
  </div>

  <div class="inputDiv">
    <input class="input" type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    <img class="error-icon" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
    <p class="error-txt">Last Name cannot be empty</p>
  </div>

  <div class="inputDiv">
    <input class="input" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <img class="error-icon" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
    <p class="error-txt">Looks like this is not an email</p>
  </div>

  <div class="inputDiv">
    <input class="input" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <img class="error-icon" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
    <p class="error-txt">Password cannot be empty</p>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="freeTrialBtn">
  Claim your free trial 
</button>
</form>




document.querySelector will only get the first element with that class it finds in the document.  You probably want to use something like e.currentTarget.parent.querySelector to get the one for the input that is being validated

I would also change your const input variable name to be inputs so you are not reusing the variable name in your foreach loop

I would delegate from the form instead of having an event listener on each field. Also there are hundreds of examples at SO on how to use custom error messages

For both callback functions, you can get the current form field using e.target. You can write less code if you just set a class name on the form field (here, invalid). And then you can use the Subsequent-sibling combinator to change the style of the image and the error text.
If you would like to remove the default validity message you need call preventDefault() on the invalid event AND set the useCapture parameter to true on the addEventListener() so that preventDefault() is called before any other event listener.


const form01 = document.forms.form01;

form01.addEventListener("invalid", getErrorMsg, true);
form01.addEventListener("input", removeErrorMsg);

function getErrorMsg(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
};

function removeErrorMsg(e) {
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
}
.inputDiv {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.error-icon {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 30px;
}

.error-txt {
  display: none;
  color: var(--CLR-RED);
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: var(--FW-BOLD);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: 0;
}

input.invalid~.error-icon,
input.invalid~.error-txt {
  display: block;
}
<form name="form01" class="formContainer">
  <div class="inputDiv">
    <input class="input" type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
    <img class="error-icon" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
    <p class="error-txt">First Name cannot be empty</p>
  </div>

  <div class="inputDiv">
    <input class="input" type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    <img class="error-icon" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
    <p class="error-txt">Last Name cannot be empty</p>
  </div>

  <div class="inputDiv">
    <input class="input" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <img class="error-icon" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
    <p class="error-txt">Looks like this is not an email</p>
  </div>

  <div class="inputDiv">
    <input class="input" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <img class="error-icon" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
    <p class="error-txt">Password cannot be empty</p>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="freeTrialBtn">
  Claim your free trial 
</button>
</form>




exactly what i was looking for thank you!

I do have a question however, Im still learning and getting to understand useCapture. I understand the basics behind it, however in this example, why was it necessary to make the first event listener set to true? was it so it can be executed first?

If I understood the assignment correctly, you are fighting with the default browser validation behavior. It will display an error for the first incorrect input only (tooltip and icon). Usually, you would want to add novalidate property on <form> and come up with your own validation, something like this:
(Also, your query selector selects first input only, you have to select parent selector and grab an array of inputs instead).


// Wait for the DOM to be fully loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  const form = document.querySelector(".formContainer");
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input"); // Select inputs with class 'input'

  // Prevent the form's default submission behavior and validate inputs manually
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from submitting

    let formIsValid = true;

    inputs.forEach(function(input) {
      if (!input.checkValidity()) {
        formIsValid = false;
        showErrorMsg(input);
      } else {
        removeErrorMsg(input);
      }
    });

    if (formIsValid) {
      // All inputs are valid, proceed with form submission or other logic
      console.log("Form submitted successfully!");
      // You can submit the form here if needed
      // form.submit();
    }
  });

  // Add event listeners to inputs to validate on input and remove errors when corrected
  inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    input.addEventListener("input", function() {
      if (input.checkValidity()) {
        removeErrorMsg(input);
      } else {
        showErrorMsg(input);
      }
    });
  });

  function showErrorMsg(input) {
    const parentDiv = input.closest(".inputDiv");
    const errorIcon = parentDiv.querySelector(".error-icon");
    const errorTxt = parentDiv.querySelector(".error-txt");

    input.classList.add('invalid'); // Optional: Add a class to style invalid inputs
    errorIcon.classList.add("active");
    errorTxt.classList.add("active");
  }

  function removeErrorMsg(input) {
    const parentDiv = input.closest(".inputDiv");
    const errorIcon = parentDiv.querySelector(".error-icon");
    const errorTxt = parentDiv.querySelector(".error-txt");

    input.classList.remove('invalid'); // Optional: Remove invalid class when input is valid
    errorIcon.classList.remove("active");
    errorTxt.classList.remove("active");
  }

});
/* Base styles for the form */
.formContainer {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.inputDiv {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px; /* Adjust spacing between inputs */
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input.invalid {
  border-color: red; /* Highlight invalid inputs */
}

::placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
}

/* Error icon styling */
.error-icon {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.error-icon.active {
  display: block;
}

/* Error text styling */
.error-txt {
  display: none;
  color: red; /* Or use var(--CLR-RED) if defined */
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: bold; /* Or use var(--FW-BOLD) if defined */
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
}

.error-txt.active {
  display: block;

}

/* Button styling */
.freeTrialBtn {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #28a745; /* Green background */
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.freeTrialBtn:hover {
  background-color: #218838; /* Darker green on hover */
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Form Validation Example</title>
  <!-- Link to your CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

  <form class="formContainer" novalidate>
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <input class="input" type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
      <img class="error-icon" src="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/svg/solid/exclamation-circle.svg" alt="Error Icon">
      <p class="error-txt">First Name cannot be empty</p>
    </div>

    <div class="inputDiv">
      <input class="input" type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
      <img class="error-icon" src="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/svg/solid/exclamation-circle.svg" alt="Error Icon">
      <p class="error-txt">Last Name cannot be empty</p>
    </div>

    <div class="inputDiv">
      <input class="input" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
      <img class="error-icon" src="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/svg/solid/exclamation-circle.svg" alt="Error Icon">
      <p class="error-txt">Looks like this is not an email</p>
    </div>

    <div class="inputDiv">
      <input class="input" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      <img class="error-icon" src="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/svg/solid/exclamation-circle.svg" alt="Error Icon">
      <p class="error-txt">Password cannot be empty</p>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="freeTrialBtn">
      Claim your free trial 
    </button>
  </form>

  <!-- Include your JavaScript file -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



